# EmEditor's indent behavior on blank lines

Tags: emeditor

Currently EmEditor inserts indent characters (spaces or tabs) as below:

```
[indent]for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
[indent][indent]printf("%d\n", i);[cursor]
```

If I press Enter twice, the text will become:

```
[indent]for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
[indent][indent]printf("%d\n", i);
[indent]
[indent][cursor]
```

As you see, the 3rd line is blank, but has an indent character which most people want to eliminate. Is there an option to let EmEditor not insert that indent character?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **Delete Spaces at End of Lines** option in the **Save Details** dialog box (configuration properties -> **File** -> **Saving...** button).

[image: EmEditor - Save Details]

Comment: In some scenarios I have to keep some of spaces and tabs at the end of some lines, e.g. text templates, but it will be helpful if the editor can automatically remove the unneeded spaces in blank lines which were made during inputting by hand.